# Time advance in Adaptive Mesh Refinement method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I am working on solving complex system of 2D PDEs governing the behaviour of plasma in a gas lamp during discharge. Recent tests have shown that because of steep gradients in temperature field and overall explosive nature of a process I won't go anywhere further without adding gas dynamics to the model. As far as I know from my mentor, there will be supersonic shocks travelling across the 5mm lamp. As far as I understand, to even think about somewhat accurate solution I first have to implement some kind of mesh refinement algorithm.

I've read Berger&Colella's LAMR for Shock Hydrodynamics, Colella's short course of block-structured AMR @Berkley, Structured AMR by Vakili and Martin,Colella,Anghel&Alexander's AMR for Multiscale Nonequilibrium physics, so I understand that there have to be performed somewhat untrivial operations during the interpolation from coarse grid onto finer ones, synchronisations between halfsteps of finer grids, averaging of finer grids onto coarse ones and some kind of flux correction to preserve conservation laws.

That brings to the question: What exactly happens during the time step in Adaptive Mesh Refinement algorithm? I would appreciate full explanation, but here are some specific questions that are likely to arise either way:

Consider parabolic problem on two-level grid, L0 & L1, L0 being the coarse one.

1) Is it correct that to get least amount of errors, I have to first advance L0 problem by time step $\tau$ as if there was no mesh refinement at all, then interpolate resulting L0 data to get boundary conditions for L1 problem at $t+\frac{\tau}{2}$ and advance L1 for $\frac{\tau}{2}$, then interpolate L0 data for L1 problem at $t+\tau$ and advance L1 fol half-step again, then average L1 data onto L0 grid and correct L0-only points adjacent to L1 boundary for flux conservation using L1 data?

1.a) During correction of L0 data using L1, do I recalculate all L1-bordering L0 points at the same time, or am I allowed to use corrected data on L0 X-point alongside with data averaged from L1 grid during my correcting of Y-point adjacent to X? (To illustrate: I am talking about something similar to difference between synchronous and asynchronous Hopfield networks).

1.b) If it is even possible, how do I synchronize grids for elliptic task? Radiative transfer is a large part of my system, too.

2) How do I generate boundary conditions on fine-fine grid boundary?

2.a) In some of the papers I've read I noticed the phrase similar to "If possible, boundary conditions are taken from the same-level grid or finer". How can this be, if at the moment of me updating the first of $L_k$ grids I do not yet have any data from the other $L_k$ or $L_{k+1}$ grids?

2.b) If the very concept of fine-fine boundary is not possible or leads to significant errors, then do I have to merge those contacting fine grids and solve the problem on the non-rectangular grid?

2.c) If I am to solve for the non-rectangular grid, what SLAE solvers besides iterative are good for sparse matrices? I was using Thomas algorithm modified for block-tridiagonal matrices, but as far as I understand, matrix for generic non-rectangular grid won't be tridiagonal.

Comment: You might want to post that question to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/